# What is user_trailingslashit() for?

Tags: functions

What does the `user_trailingslashit()` function do, and when should I use it? How is it different from the `trailingslashit()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`trailingslashit()`](http://queryposts.com/function/trailingslashit/) function adds a `/` to the end of a URL if it lacks one.

[`user_trailingslashit()`](http://queryposts.com/function/user_trailingslashit/) uses the permalink template as set under *Settings > Permalinks* to decide whether to add or remove the trailing slash from the end of the URL

For example, if you had the permalink format set to `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` (note the trailing slash), `user_trailingslashit()` would append a trailing slash to the URL passed in as the first parameter.

If the permalink format was `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%` (no trailing slash), any trailing slash on the URL would be stripped off.

Basically, `user_trailingslashit()` forces the URL to be consistent with what is set in the permalink preferences.